# Silent push notification vs. normal push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I send from my webspace via PHP push notifications to my swift 2 app.
I do it like this was:

```
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'HELLO', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
```

Now I would like to working with silent push notifications, too.
I learned, that I can send silent push like this:

```
$body['aps'] = array('content-available' => 1);
```

And in my app delegate I do something after receiving a silent push.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

   print("DO SOMETHING IN THE BACKGROUND")

    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
  }
  return
}
```

This works fine.
But the problem now, is that this print will be come each time, if I send a normal push, too.

That is not correct. The print "DO SOMETHING IN THE BACKGROUND" should only execute if a silent push will be receive.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could inspect the payload of the notification to see if it has the content-available property equal to 1.

Comment: thanks :) something like that i tried for a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code in the following way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if let apsValue = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if (apsValue["content-available"] as? Int == 1){
           print("DO SOMETHING IN THE BACKGROUND")
           handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
        }

    }
return
}
```

Right now your action item is being executed every single time but the above code will filter it out so that it only executes when there is a silent push (which as you know is indicated by the content available = 1 flag.)